# Can I change the isolation (sandbox) setting of a workflow from inside Visual Studio so that I can deploy from there?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using VS2010 with the CRM Developer Tools extension, to develop a custom workflow for an in-house CRM 2011 target.  The MSDN help is pretty good but I can't find an answer to this one: if I choose 'Deploy' either from the Build menu or the CRM Package right-click menu, I get the isolation mode exception that many have enquired about here.

I am OK with running the workflow with 'sandbox' settings, but I cannot find anywhere in VS2010 where I can tell the 'Deploy' option to use this setting.  That means that I have to use the stand-alone Plug-in Registration Tool to deploy the workflow - not a disaster, but a little inconvenient.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CRMPackage project, you can find `RegisterFile.crmregister` file.

Open it in xml editor, find a solution element for your assembly.

`<Solution Assembly="yor.assembly.name.dll" Id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsolationMode="None" SourceType="Database">`

Modifying value of IsolationMode attribute to `None` or `Sandbox` will let you set up whatever you need.

Comment: I'm not sure where I am supposed to thank you if not here, so thanks - worked a treat!